# What is "ng2" referenced along with Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I see many references to ng2 in most of the blogs that talk about Angular 2.

What does this ng2 refer to? Is ng2 the CLI of Angular 2?

Comment: ng2 = Angular 2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**`Angular1.x`** is popular by its in-built directives start with **`ng`**.
 **`ng-###`** **eg** *ng-hide*, *ng-show* & etc. 
So everyone started calling **`Angular1.x`** by **`ng`** or **`ng1`** (*`ng1` after `Angular2.0` came*).

Later, **`Angular2.0`** came up so people started calling it **`ng2`**.

Now **`Angular1.x`** is known as former version of Angular that is **`ng`** or **`ng1`**.

and

To refer to **`Angular2.0`**, people use **`ng2`** term,

People have already started using **`ng2`** name everywhere to refer to **`Angular2.0`** eg. blogs, Stackoverflow etc.

*Please take a note that Angular2's directives don't start with **`ng2-###`***

Comment: It is worth noting, that Angular >2 has fast release cycle (currently Angular 4). Some people call it `ngx` now. For example, most popular twitter bootstrap module is named `ngx-bootstrap` in NPM.

Comment: My dear friend @ArekŻelechowski, you could see the date on which this was answered. its too old answer when it was going through Angular-2.0.x.

Answer (score 7):

The common received abbreviation for Angular is `ng`. This is simply because the English language pronunciation of `ng` as *en-gee* can sound *similar* (not really) to Angular.

So in that context ng2 just simply is an abbreviation for Angular2.

Comment: I think it _does_ sound similar. Try *eng* as in "english", sounds like a short way to say "Ang"--ular

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean, but Angular 2 CLI is invoked with `ng`, so `ng g component new-component` or `ng serve`.

You could be referring to shorthand reference ng2 -> Angular2.

And for more info on Angular 2 CLI you can checkout github repo. It's still in beta version though https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Did you see it somewhere in code, or just blog posts?